# Can anyone tell me how can I output null to empty values using jackson mapper in spring Rest?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have tried the solutions to above that I found on stackoverflow. But they didn't do what I wanted the controller to do. I don't want to change getter/setter method in every class to convert the null values to empty values. I am looking for a solution which will allow me to do this at global level using object mapper, by configuration perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this bean in your configuration class:

```
@Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureObjectMapper() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(new NullSerializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
        builder.configure(objectMapper);
        return builder;
    }
```

NullSerializer class:

```
public class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        // any JSON value you want...
        gen.writeString("");
    }
}
```

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Thanks and this solution does not work...I have mentioned that I have tried the stack overflow solutions and they dont work. its not printing anything anymore even the values that are not null.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks and this solution does not work...I have mentioned that I have tried the stack overflow solutions and they dont work. its not printing anything anymore even the values that are not null.